# How can I fix this error in my go project - undefined: bson.RegEx

Tags: regex, mongodb, go, bson

I get the following error from my editor: 
`undefined: bson.RegEx`

due to this line of code in my go project:

`regex := bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: id, Options: "i"}}`

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

I've made sure that I'm importing:

`"go.mongdb.org/mongo-driver/bson"`

I've also checked inside `bson/primitive/primitive.go` to see that `RegEx` does exist

Using version `1.1.0` of mongo-driver.

Comment: You don't say which version you're using, but [the current version](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson) doesn't export `RegEx`. It also doesn't have a file `bson/primitive.go`, so I'm not sure what you're looking at, unless it's a really old version.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to work around the problem by **removing** this:

```
regex := bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: id, Options: "i"}}
```

and **add** this instead:

```
regex := `(?i).*` + name + `.*`
filter = bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$regex": regex}}
```

Comment: I doubt you need `.*`, use ```regex := `(?i)` + name```. Most probably you also need to escape thd `name`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Using [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) v1+, you can utilise `bson.primitive`. For example:

```
patternName := `.*` + name + `.*`
filter := bson.M{"name": primitive.Regex{Pattern: patternName, Options:"i"}}
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
```

This is imported from `"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"`.

In addition, I would also suggest to consider the search pattern. You can optimise a regex search if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. For example, `^name.*` will be optimised by matching only against the values from the index that starts with `name`.

Also worth noting that case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilise case-insensitive indexes. Please see [$regex index use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) for more information.

Depending on the use case, consider [MongoDB Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/). For example, you can create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text):

```
db.collection.createIndex({"name":"text"});
```

Which then you can search using:

```
filter := bson.M{"$text": bson.M{"$search": name}}
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
```

Also worth mentioning depending on your requirements, there's also [MongoDB Atlas Full Text Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/full-text-search/) feature for advanced search functionality. i.e. [text analysers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/full-text-search/analyzers/#analyzers-ref).